# Can't find my AWS shared AMI when trying to share with specific account

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-ami

I followed the instructions to share my AMI with a specific account here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/sharingamis-explicit.html

I made sure the account number is correct, and when I log into the target account, I'm unable to find the shared AMI anywhere in my EC2 console ( Under Images -> AMIs ) no matter what I try to filter by.

How can I find the shared AMI?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I'm not sure about shared AMIs, but many things in EC2 are segmented by region and you have to select the correct region to see them. You can select the region in the upper right-hand corner of the screen.

Answer (score 4):

Besides making sure you're in the right region, you might check if you're not filtering by "Owned by me" which is the default. You need to filter by "Private images" as per the following documentation:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/usingsharedamis-finding.html

Comment: That subtle "Owned by me" filter was hosing me up! Thanks @rui